# How to start libvirtd with --listen option in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, openstack

I can't get libvirtd to start with -l (listen) option in 16.04
Changes to /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf and /etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf seem to have no effect. And changes to /etc/default/libvirt-bin cause libvirtd to fail to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Self solution:

Edit /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf to add/change:

```
listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
auth_tcp = "none"
```

Then edit /etc/default/libvirtd to add:

```
libvirtd_opts="-l"
```

Then:

```
sudo service libvirt-bin restart
```